# how to use echarts in my react-native project

Tags: react-native, echarts

i tried to use echarts-for-react  github.com/hustcc/echarts-for-react, but failed
[code is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXp5X.png)

[error is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1VEI.png)

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/wuba/wrn-echarts, React Native version of Apache Echarts, based on react-native-svg and react-native-skia. Much better performance than webview based solution.

```
// import { SvgChart, SVGRenderer } from 'wrn-echarts';
import SvgChart, { SVGRenderer } from 'wrn-echarts/lib/module/svgChart';
import * as echarts from 'echarts/core';
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  BarChart,
} from 'echarts/charts';
import {
  TitleComponent,
  TooltipComponent,
  GridComponent,
} from 'echarts/components';

// register extensions
echarts.use([
  TitleComponent,
  TooltipComponent,
  GridComponent,
  SVGRenderer,
  // ...
  BarChart,
])

const E_HEIGHT = 250;
const E_WIDTH = 300;

// initial
function SvgComponent({ option }) {
  const svgRef = useRef<any>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let chart: any;
    if (svgRef.current) {
      // @ts-ignore
      chart = echarts.init(svgRef.current, 'light', {
        renderer: 'svg',
        width: E_WIDTH,
        height: E_HEIGHT,
      });
      chart.setOption(option);
    }
    return () => chart?.dispose();
  }, [option]);

  return <SvgChart ref={svgRef} />;
}

// Component usage
export default function App() {
  const option = {
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    },
    yAxis: {
      type: 'value',
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
        type: 'bar',
      },
    ],
  }
  return <SvgComponent option={option} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the react babel presets npm package.

Try this:

```
npm i --save-dev babel-preset-react
```